# What does AOF stand for?

Tags: memory, definition

I found [this page](https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo), saying

> All paid plans have AOF enabled to log write operations every second as well as RDB backups to S3 daily or on-demand.

I know RDB means relational database, but what does AOF mean in this context?

Comment: Maybe this: Append-Only File, a software technique of logging database updates for persistence.

Comment: Just saying, this took about 10 seconds on google to find OP.

Comment: There's far too many TLA's (three-letter acronyms)...

Comment: @dbillz I searched on Google many times "What does AOF stand for?" "What does AOF stand for computer programming?" but after you posted the comment I tried again with "What does AOF mean?" which worked. I also searched on dictionaries

Comment: Why the downvotes? I searched for a few minutes before posting this.

Comment: Worth nothing to mention that RDB doesn't always stands for "Relational Database". For example, RDB on Redis context stands for "Redis Database[ file]".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Append-Only File**

Because there are no seeks or re-writing, it is typically immune to corruption problems due to dirty shutdown.

Redis uses AOF for persistence, and has a good writeup of advantages/disadvantages in their use case: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 4):

[Append Only File](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

> the AOF persistence logs every write operation received by the server, that will be played again at server startup, reconstructing the original dataset. Commands are logged using the same format as the Redis protocol itself, in an append-only fashion. Redis is able to rewrite the log on background when it gets too big.